# Exponential distribution conditional probability

Tags: probability-theory, exponential-distribution

> Let $X_1 \sim \boldsymbol\exp (\lambda_1)$ and $X_2 \sim \boldsymbol\exp (\lambda_2)$. Then, 
>   $$\mathbb{P} \{X_1 < X_2 | X_1 = x\} = \mathbb{P}\{x < X_2 \}.$$
>   (Ross Introduction to Probability Models page 302)

Yet, if I use the definition of the conditional expectation $$\mathbb{P}\{A|B\} = \mathbb{P}\{A \cap B\} / \mathbb{P}\{A\},$$ we get devision by zero, because the probability $\mathbb{P}\{X_1 = x\}$ is zero since $X_1$ follows a continous distribution. What am I missing here?

Comment: Roughly, use $\Bbb P(\{X_1<X_2\} \mid \{X_1=x\}) ~=~ \lim_{0<h\to 0}\dfrac{\Bbb P\{x-h\leq X_1\leq x<X_2\}}{\Bbb P\{x-h\leq X_1\leq x\}}$  (with appropriate care to avoid a Bertrand Paradox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exponential distribution is irrelevant. The independence assumption, which is relevant, is missing.

The following fact follows from Fubini.

> **Fact** For independent $X_1,X_2$ and measurable (say, bounded) $f$,
>   $$
> \mathrm{E} [f(X_1,X_2)] = \mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[f(x,X_2)]|_{x=X_1}].
> $$

In our case, for any measurable $A$,
$$
\mathrm{E} [\mathbf{1}_{X_1<X_2} \mathbf{1}_{X_1\in A}] = \mathrm{E} [\mathrm{E} [\mathbf{1}_{x<X_2}]|_{x=X_1} \mathbf{1}_{X_1\in A}] = \mathrm{E} [\mathrm{P}(x<X_2)|_{x=X_1} \mathbf{1}_{X_1\in A}],
$$
whence *by definition*
$$
\mathrm{P} [{X_1<X_2}\mid X_1 = x] = \mathrm{E} [\mathbf{1}_{X_1<X_2}\mid X_1 = x] = \mathrm{P}(x<X_2).
$$

Comment: Thanks a lottt!